# Entity Cache for paragraphs

Tags: caching, drupal, entity, paragraphs

Can anybody tell me if 'entity_cache' does cache paragraph entities as well?
I have seen that there was a patch a year ago... I wonder if it might be in module by now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a feature request for a Drupal nodule, which could be answered in that Module issue queue. SO is not the place for tracking feature request in software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its implemented currently in https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache